# Jdk1.7.0_10 with eclipse Juno

Tags: windows-7, java, eclipse, path, jdk

I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java Developers for  Windows 64 Bit from  - [eclipse download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/juno/SR1/eclipse-java-juno-SR1-win32-x86_64.zip) , and also jdk-7u9-windows-i586.exe from [oracle downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u9-downloads-1859576.html) .

Then I installed the JDK in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10` , and when I run the above eclipse I get  -

[image]

> A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse.
>
> No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following
>   locations:
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\eclipse_juno_java_developer\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe in your
>   current PATH

Likely the problem is in the Environment variables

[image]

I have in **User variable

```
PATH =  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\bin;
```

and in system variable

```
JAVA_HOME  = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
PATH =  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
```

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit Service Pack 1.

Any solution? What is wrong here?

Comment: I could be well off, but I had so many issues with Eclipse, multiple reboots helped, so try and see if the problem persists

Comment: In quick observation you see something wrong ?

Comment: No, nothing obvious, other than it's looking for something it can't see. And I assume it has been installed, hence a reboot may just put complete any installation process

Comment: looks like you're mixing Eclipse 64-bit & JRE/JDK 32-bit - don't mix & match, either stick to both 32-bit or 64-bit

Comment: @Sathya : I have OS 64 bit and I want only eclipse and jdk for 64 bit  . Does `jdk-7u9-windows-i586.exe` is not for 64 bit  ?

Comment: @URL87 yeah, that's the 32-bit version, further confirmed by the fact that it's installed in program files(x86) folder, which is generally for 32-bit programs

Comment: @Sathya : So you recommend to download the `windows x64` version from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html "here") ?

Comment: @URL87 yes, that should work. Don't forget to change the path etc

Comment: @URL87 great, I've posted an answer based on the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you've installed 64-bit version of Eclipse & on top of that, installed the 32-bit version of JRE/JDK. And then you're forcing the path - it's not a good idea to mix and match 32-bit / 64-bit dependencies.

I'd recommend you to uninstall both, remove the path changes you've done and stick to either 32-bit Eclipse/32-bit JRE/JDK or 64-bit Eclipse/64-bit JRE/JDK.

Once you've done that, all should be fine